# spring-data-cassandra CassandraBatchTemplate is not public

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I want to use CassandraBatchTemplate's withTimestamp to insert client side timestamp like USING TIMESTAMP clause in the CQL. here is my code:

```
  @Bean
  public DseSession dseSession(DseCluster dseCluster) {
    return dseCluster.connect(keyspace);
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate(DseSession session) {
    return new CassandraTemplate(session);
  }

  @Bean
  public CassandraBatchOperations cassdraBatchTemplate(CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate) {
    return new CassandraBatchTemplate(cassandraTemplate);
  }
```

when compiled it complained cannot find CassandraBatchTemplate even though i can see it in spring-data-cassandra source code. one thing i noticed is that CassandraBatchTemplate is default implementation of interface CassandraBatchOperations, thus no 'public' is applied to CassandraBatchTemplate class:

```
class CassandraBatchTemplate implements CassandraBatchOperations {...}
```

if the class is not public then I cannot create an instance of it by 'new'. how to work around? I'm using spring-data-cassandra 2.1.10.RELEASE and dse-java-driver-core 1.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CassandraBatchTemplate` isn't public because it has a very limited lifecycle. It isn't intended to be used as `@Bean` because it is only valid for a single execution.

Instead, obtain `CassandraBatchOperations` through `CassandraOperations.batchOps()`.